# How do I combine multiple GCP alerting conditions so that only one incident is created?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, gcp-alerts

I'm trying to create an alerting policy for a Gauge type metric in Google Cloud Platform that is expected to trigger when:

- the gauge's value is below 1
- data is absent

Using Terraform, I came up with the following definition:

```
resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy_prometheus_metric" {
  display_name = "Metric check failed"

  conditions {
    display_name = "Metric violation"
    condition_threshold {
      filter                  = "resource.type = \"prometheus_target\" AND resource.labels.cluster = \"${var.cluster_name}\" AND metric.type = \"prometheus.googleapis.com/elasticsearch_cluster_health_status/gauge\" AND metric.labels.color = \"green\""
      evaluation_missing_data = "EVALUATION_MISSING_DATA_ACTIVE"
      comparison              = "COMPARISON_LT"
      duration                = "60s"
      trigger {
        count = 1
      }
      threshold_value = 1
    }
  }
  conditions {
    display_name = "Metric absent"
    condition_absent {
      duration = "120s"
      filter   = "resource.type = \"prometheus_target\" AND resource.labels.cluster = \"${var.cluster_name}\" AND metric.type = \"prometheus.googleapis.com/elasticsearch_cluster_health_status/gauge\" AND metric.labels.color = \"green\""
    }
  }
  combiner = "OR"
  notification_channels = [
    "${var.monitoring_email_group_name}"
  ]
}
```

This does work, however it creates two separate incidents when the following happens:

1. the metric starts being absent
2. the metric then reappears in a below 1 state

This is surprising to me as I use `OR` as the combiner for the conditions. Is there anything I can do to merge the two conditions into a single incident?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the multi condition trigger is set to “`Any condition is met`”(i.e., combiner value is "OR") and if condition 1 or 2 is met, only a single incident is created.

When the multi condition trigger is set to “`All conditions are met`” and both conditions are met, two incidents are created. One incident for the event that got over the threshold for condition 1 . One incident for the event that got over the threshold for condition 2.

When the multi condition trigger is set to “`All conditions are met`” and one condition out of two is met, there is no incident created.

I found in the following [document](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/concepts-indepth#number-of-notifications%5C), that it is not possible from your end to reduce the amount of alerts to 1 when there are multiple conditions. In the shared document it is mentioned that this feature is currently not available to you:“

> You can't configure Cloud Monitoring to create a single incident and
> send a single notification when the policy contains multiple
> conditions.

This feature could be implemented for GCP alerting and incidents “momentarily”. Indeed there was a similar request that was raised by one GCP customer and you can track that in this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/194210681).

**Note:** Once take a look at “`All conditions are met even for different resources for each condition`” (i.e., combiner value is "AND").